# Binding on the View - how to get the details of parent property from a child list

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I am using Xamarin forms.

I have a simple View that contains a couple of list views. The whole view has a BindingContext with a viewmodel. The view model class contains a BackgroundColor.
Question: How can I access the BackgroundColor property from within the listview's dataTemplate.

ViewModel.cs

```
public class TestViewModel {
 public System.Drawing.Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
 public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

An instance of the above class is set a BindingContext to the view
View.xaml

```
<ContextPage.... >
....
 <listview  ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"...
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">

</ContentPage>
```

The above grid's background does not work as the current context is now on the Employee collection. So how can I access the "BackgroundColor" within the view model when in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundColor of Grid control in Xamarin has Xamarin.Forms.Color type, but not System.Drawing.Color, so you must change type in your class.

```
public class TestViewModel {
 public Xamarin.Forms.Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
 public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:

You can use RelativeSource FindAncestor to get desired property from TestViewModel instance.

Here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713316/1979354

Comment: Agree, but how do I map that property when I am within the list view datatemplate?

<ContextPage.... >
....
 <listview  ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"...
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"> = this does not work unless I have a property within the Employee class itself which stores background color

</ContentPage>

Comment: @Peter, i have updated answer, you need relative source to get value from parent context, when you in template.

Comment: I had to tweak couple of things from there, may be you can add this to your answer
{Binding BackgroundColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}, Mode=FindAncestor}}

It should be Source={RelativeSource.. in Xamarin 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType = does not work and complaints RelativeSource is not in the BindingExtension

Thanks mate, for getting that link.